# combineLatest is not emitting when the second observable changes?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

[This is a stackblitz demo of the below code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/slice-reactive-collection).

There are two observables - `active$` - `collection$`:

```
const central:EStore<Todo> = new EStore();
const collection:EStore<Todo> = new EStore();
const active$ = central.observeActive();
const collection$ = collection.observe();
```

When `collection$` notifies, as logged in this statement:

```
collection$.subscribe(v=>console.log('Todo added to collection'));
```

This `combineLatest` function does not fire:

```
const isActiveTodoInCollection$:Observable<boolean> = 
     combineLatest(active$, 
                   collection$, 
                   (a, c)=>{
                     console.log("Firing");
      if (getMapValue(central.active)) {
             return collection.containsById(getMapValue(central.active));
      }
      return false;               
});
```

However if we cause the `active$` observable to notify, the `isActiveTodoInCollection$` observable will fire.

Why does it not fire when the `collection$` observable notifies?

Another odd thing is that this will produce a logging statement when `collection$` notifies:

```
const t$ = combineLatest(collection$, (c)=>console.log("collection$ performing a notification"));

t$.subscribe();
```

But if we add the `active$` observable to the arguments it stops notifying.  It's as if `active$` has to notify first ...

Comment: combineLatest works only when each of the observables emits a value atleast once. I think the observeActive() , in your case fires only when you call central.addActive(todo); https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html#why-use-combinelatest

Comment: You nailed it - Great observation - Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

combineLatest works only when each of the observables emits a value at least once.

The central.post(todo) doesn't really complete because observeActive() in your case really observes only when central.addActive(todo) is called, hence there isn't anything to combine.

example to illustrate the issue, comment two$ in the below code and uncomment the following line, you will see the difference

```
import { combineLatest, Observable } from "rxjs";

const one$ = new Observable(subscriber => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("set");
    subscriber.next(42);
  }, 1000);
});

const two$ = new Observable(subscriber => {});

// comment above two$ and uncomment this
/*const two$ = new Observable(subscriber => {
  subscriber.next(56);
});*/

combineLatest(one$, two$).subscribe(([one, two]) => {
  console.log(
    ` One Latest: ${one},
      Two Latest: ${two}`
  );
});
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-vaughan-1t9k0